# No error on statement without semicolon

Tags: c, statements

```
     #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {

    int a,b;
    b=10;

    a=b--;
    printf("a=%d b=%d\n",a,b);

    a=b---           //Here why i didn't get error....???
    printf("a=%d b=%d\n",a,b);

                     //a=b---- or a=b---; //for these, i got error

    a=b--;
    printf("a=%d b=%d\n",a,b);

    }
```

why statement `b---` doesn't show error. Can i say this is a bug...? If no, please explain what's going on internally...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) returns `int`, so you have a syntactically valid statement<sup>*</sup>. This

```
a=b---
printf("a=%d b=%d\n",a,b);
```

is a single statement, which is *exactly* the same as this:

```
a = b-- - printf("a=%d b=%d\n",a,b);
```

or, for extra clarity,

```
a = (b--) - printf("a=%d b=%d\n", a, b);
```

In other words, for `ints` `x` and `y`, `x--- y` is parsed as `(x--) - y`.

---

<sup>* While syntactically valid, the statement itself is *undefined behaviour*, since there is a modification and a read of `b` without an intervening sequence point</sup>

Comment: But i didnot mention any semicolon..?

Comment: @ANBU.SANKAR It is a cut and paste of your code, with out a newline and with an extra space for clarity only.

Comment: @Anbu ..you are actually wirting only one line not two lines , so you dont need an statement terminator. You are subtracting the return vaalue of printf which is int from an integer which is absolutely valid

Comment: @ANBU.SANKAR The point is that semi-colons denote the end of an expression. Newlines are ignored.

Comment: @ANBU.SANKAR Because it is not valid in the context where you are using it?

Answer (score 3):

Function `printf` has return type `int`.

From the C Standard

> 3 The printf function returns the number of characters transmitted, or
>   a negative value if an output or encoding error occurred.

So this statement

```
a=b---           //Here why i didn't get error....???
    printf("a=%d b=%d\n",a,b);
```

is a valid C statement. It can be rewritten for descriptive reason as

```
a = b-- - printf("a=%d b=%d\n",a,b);
```

or

```
int tmp = printf("a=%d b=%d\n",a,b);
a = b-- - tmp;
```

Take into account that the original statement has undefined behaviour because it is unspecified when the side effect of expression b-- will be applied to b. But in any case the code will be compiled.

Answer (score 2):

```
a=b---           //Here why i didn't get error....???
    printf("a=%d b=%d\n",a,b);
```

This is a single statement and is valid since it is being teminated by semicolon.

Printf returns integer , so integer-integer which is valid opertion

```
//a=b---- or a=b---; //for these, i got error
```

Here , the above staments are syntactically incorrect as you are using only one operand for binary operator subtraction which indeed is invalid.

So , it has thrown the error. hope this clarifies a bit.